# How to implement Async method calls in Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous

Is there is way to implement Async method call in java Other than thread and Executor ? If it is implementing by Executor will it introduce any delay ?

Comment: Everything you add introduces a delay.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Threads` *is* the way in Java. `Executors` is just a way to wrap thread management in a nicer container.

It *might* introduce a delay. If the thread(s) are busy working another task there will be a delay. Otherwise the delay is based on the OS context-switching mechanism which generally is quite responsive (which in turn may vary on a multicore architecture, and architectures based on hyper threading or similar technologies).

Comment: You mean to say the delay introduced in the Executors depends on the threadpool and the availability of worker thread

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DynamicProxy (core java feature) to introduce a layer inbetween the caller and the callee. In the proxy you have the method call represented as an object. Return immediately and call the method in a separate thread. A question remains how to return values to the caller. Do you plan to have return values that you want to return later? This might be solved using a callback method.

Comment: No i dont want to return anything .

Answer (score -1):

You can pass in a class that implements your callback.

```
new A(instanceOfB);

someMethodOfA() {
    doSomething();
    instanceOfB.callback();
}
```